# How to set log level when using AWS JavaScript SDK v3 @aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-js

This is how I log to AWS CloudWatch logs:

```js
import {CloudWatchLogsClient, PutLogEventsCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs'

const cloudWatchLogsClient = new CloudWatchLogsClient({region: REGION})
const logToCloudWatch = async (message) => {
    await cloudWatchLogsClient.send(new PutLogEventsCommand({
        logEvents: [{
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            message: message
        }],
        logGroupName: 'my_group',
        logStreamName: 'my_stream'
    }))
}

await logToCloudWatch('INFO: App started with env: ' + JSON.stringify(process.env, null, 2))

try {
    dosomething()
} catch (err) {
    await logToCloudWatch('ERROR: ' + err))
}
```

As you can see, I'm just prefixing messages with log levels which is quite ugly.  Does @aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs support log levels?  How do I use them?

Comment: I think you would typically use a logger such as winston and a package such as [winston-cloudwatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-cloudwatch). Example [here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/set-up-a-logger-for-your-node-app-with-winston-and-cloudwatch-in-5-minutes-dec0c6c0d5b8).